# How to get an element value that is not showing in html code with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, testing, cypress

this is the code of my element

```
<input type="text" class="nameOfClass" id="someid" name="somename" maxlength="255" placeholder="justholder" ng-model="model" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-animation="false" style="">
```

as you can see there is no attribute value, but I can clearly see that there is text in that text field in web app I am trying to automate.

So my problem is, that I don't know how to get value of the text field.
I've tried google chrome inspector to find where is the value but without any luck. Somewhere I read, that caching can causing this problem, but in the network console I can see the values in request response.

Thanks

Comment: Your explaination is hard to understand.

Comment: If I understood correctly, So you are typing something in the input field and then you want to read that typed value ?

Comment: Have you checked to see if the value is set after shifting focus from the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the value written in the text field, you can get it by invoking `val`.

```js
cy.get('#someid')
  .invoke('val')
  .then((value) => {
    cy.log(value) //logs the value
  })
```

If you want to apply any assertion on the value, you can:

```js
cy.get('#someid').should('have.value', 'your-value')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to `type="text"`, that's not the text the user types in - it's an attribute that tells the input what values to allow.

You can also have `type="number"`, `type="date"`, `type="color"`, [etc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#input_types)

Checking that input is of type "text" would be done with this,

```js
cy.get('input#someid').should('have.attr', 'type', 'text')
```

Checking the value property would be done like this

```js
cy.get('input#someid')
  .type('entering a value')     // there's nothing in value yet
  .should('have.value', 'entering a value')
```